# How can I customize the virtualenv info in zsh theme?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, linux-terminal, konsole, virtualenv

I use the bureau theme (little customized) with oh-my-zsh.

[.zshrc file](https://github.com/vchrombie/dotfiles/blob/master/zshrc)

[zsh-theme file](https://github.com/vchrombie/dotfiles/blob/master/vchrombie-bureau.zsh-theme)

```
p0tt3r@wand ~                                  [21:19:10] ()
>$                                                       
                                                            
p0tt3r@wand ~                                  [21:19:20] ()
>$ source dev/sources/VENV_DIR/bin/activate              
                                                            
p0tt3r@wand ~                                  [21:19:23] ()
(VENV_DIR) >$ deactivate                                 
                                                            
p0tt3r@wand ~                                  [21:19:32] ()
>$
```

I want to replace the brackets beside the date with the virtual environment name. This would be the sample.

```
p0tt3r@wand ~                          [21:19:23] (VENV_DIR)
>$
```

I want to customize the theme accordingly. I am not sure if this is possible, but I would like to know the solution if it is.

Comment: What have you tried? I think the answer to the first question when searching for "zsh prompt" on SU  should send you on the right track (`setopt PROMPT_SUBST`)...

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mpy, I tried some solutions like adding virtualenv to the zsh plugins and using the virtualenv variable but of no use, instead, it broke the system (the virtualenv name doesnt appear after activating, I had to revert the changes to bring it back to normal).